# Webpack 2: SASS themes with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, sass, webpack

Webpack 2.2.1, Angular 2.4.7.

I'm creating a site that has multiple themes using SASS, but haven't been able to get Webpack to create individual CSS files for each theme.  ExtractTextPlugin shows promise because it creates a separate CSS file for each entry point, but not the theme specific ones I need.  Is there any way to have each ThemeX.scss be output as something like /themes/ThemeX.css?  *Note that the themes are named differently, but I'm using names like ThemeA.css for the sake of brevity.  They're actually Sales.css, Engineers.css, etc.*

Example directory structure for the themes is:

```
src/assets/styles/themes/ThemeA/ThemeA.scss 
src/assets/styles/themes/ThemeB/ThemeB.scss
```

**Webpack config**

```
const extractThemePlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin("themes/[name].css");

{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: helpers.root('src/assets/styles/themes'),
    use: extractThemePlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
    })
}

plugins: [ extractThemePlugin, ...and others ]
```

---

**Things I've tried**

**1:** Setting each of the ThemeX.scss files as an entry point:

```
entry: {               
   'main': './src/main.browser.ts',
   'themeA': helpers.root('src/assets/styles/themes/themeA/themeA.scss'),
   'themeB': helpers.root('src/assets/styles/themes/themeB/themeB.scss')
}
```

which creates the individual files, but each of them is a copy of the other, so ThemeA.css, ThemeB.css and ThemeC.css all contain the contents of ThemeA.css.

**2:** Importing each of the themes in the root app.module.ts.  This just bundles the files into a single CSS file.

**3:** Creating an ExtractTextPlugin instance for each theme.  This also creates files with duplicated content, similar to #1.

```
const extractThemeAPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin("themes/themeA.css");
const extractThemeBPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin("themes/themeB.css");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple regex match in config section of your webpack instead of just having a single extracttext entry:

First put this at the top of webpack config:

```
let extractTheme1 = new ExtractTextPlugin('theme1.css');
let extractTheme2 = new ExtractTextPlugin('theme2.css');
```

Then in config:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/i,
    exclude: [
        /theme2\.scss$/i
    ],
    use: [extractTheme1.extract('css-loader'),
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
    ]
},

// SCSS Loader
{
    test: /theme2\.scss$/i,
    use: [extractTheme2.extract('css-loader'),
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
    ]
},
```

And in plugin section:

```
plugins: [
   ...
   extractTheme1,
   extractTheme2
   ...
]
```

Comment: That got me on the right track.  Instead of using excludes (which would have been a nightmare because I have 5+ themes), I just set the test to match each theme.  I then had to include HtmlWebpackExcludeAssetsPlugin to prevent HtmlWebpackPlugin from creating link elements for each theme.